# Using different schedules for different jobs (YAML)

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to setup a pipeline that has 2 defined schedules, one to execute script x in job 1, and one to execute script y in job 2.

Ill try and show in the snippet what I need as well:

```
schedules:
- cron: '0 16 * * *'
  displayName: 'schedule 1'
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: True
- cron: '0 4 * * *'
  displayName: 'schedule 2'
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: True



jobs:
- job: job x
  condition: eq( variables.schedule, 'schedule 1')
  ...
- job: job y
  condition: eq( variables.schedule, 'schedule 2')
```

I defined both schedules, they run correctly, however I cant seem to figure out how to have the jobs 'condition' comply with the current run schedule.

I cannot find anything about pre defined variables saying anything about the schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it should be spitted into two separate pipelines, if they have to share other jobs you could import them as a [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) to avoid code duplication.

If for some reason they have to be in the same pipeline, you could create a simple script that will check if current time is closer to `schedule 1` or `schedule 2` and based on the [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages#use-the-output-variable-from-a-job-in-a-condition-in-a-subsequent-job) skip one of the job:
`condition: eq(dependencies.Foo.outputs['CheckTime.skipJob'], 'schedule 1')`

Answer (score 0):

The predefined variable [Build.CronSchedule.DisplayName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/schedules-cron?view=azure-pipelines#buildcronscheduledisplayname-variable) can be used for condition decision. An example is also given in the link.

For the given case:

```
schedules:
- cron: '0 16 * * *'
  displayName: 'schedule 1'
  branches:
  include:
  - master
  always: True
- cron: '0 4 * * *'
  displayName: 'schedule 2'
  branches:
  include:
  - master
  always: True
...

jobs:
- job: job x
  condition: eq(variables['Build.CronSchedule.DisplayName'], 'schedule 1')

...
- job: job y
  condition: eq(variables['Build.CronSchedule.DisplayName'], 'schedule 2')
```